# c programming check if key pressed without stopping program

Tags: c, windows

as you know, when using getch() in windows, the applications waits for you until you press a key,

how can i read a key without freezing the program , example :

```
void main(){
  char   c;
  while(1){
  printf("hello\n");
  if (c=getch()) {
  .
  .
  .
  }  
}
```

thank you.

Comment: What kind of app is this? Console/WinForms etc

Comment: `main()` returns an `int` by the way :)

Comment: that was just an example ..

Comment: Try `kbhit()` from `<conio.h>`, I believe.  And `main()` should return an `int`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler what compilers still use conio.h?

Comment: @Joe: Some of the ones used by people working on Windows asking that question here on SO...A search on SO for `kbhit [c]` turns up 80+ questions.  And `getch()` comes from the same header, so it is reasonable to suppose that if they can use `getch()` they can also `kbhit()`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `kbhit()` to check if a key is pressed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h> /* getch() and kbhit() */

int
main()
{
    char c;

    for(;;){
        printf("hello\n");
        if(kbhit()){
            c = getch();
            printf("%c\n", c);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

More info here: http://www.programmingsimplified.com/c/conio.h/kbhit

Comment: One should not use conio.h its very old header file and its non standard.

Comment: There is an error in this code, it will print hello indefinitely.

Comment: @user10191234: same as OP wanted, right? it will print "hello" in a loop and what ever key that is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

I needed similar functionality in a console application in Linux, but Linux don't provide `kbhit` function. On searching Google, I found an implementation at -

http://www.flipcode.com/archives/_kbhit_for_Linux.shtml