# How to run a periodic action until a key is pressed

Tags: c, pause

I'm writing a test script for an embedded controller and some of the tests require a user action before you can progress.

I print an instruction on the screen such as

```
printf("Turn switch A to ON position then press any key");
```

I then want the script to wait until the user presses a key to progress to the test

```
ExpectedSwitchState = ON;
CheckSwitch(01);
```

I could do this fairly easily with (albeit requiring enter to be pressed)

```
printf("\nPress Enter to continue");
getChar();
```

The problem I have is that I have to ensure my tool sends a tester present message every 4 seconds, if no other commands are being transmitted.  And I want it to resume as soon as a key is pressed, not wait another 4 seconds.

I'm more used to embedded C than anything using computer inputs so am not sure if there are common commands to achieve what I want.

Any advice would be appreciated.

At present I have only found ways to pause the program.  Not a way to continue doing something until a key is pressed.

I could create a while loop which increments a counter every 1ms and then transmits tester present whenever the counter gets to 4,000.  And exit the while loop if a key is pressed.  Seems a little convoluted.  And I don't know the commands to detect a key is pressed.

Comment: please add the programming language you want to use

Comment: I am programming in C, running the script on a windows PC.

Comment: POSIX `select()`? https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html

Comment: maybe duplicate: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547471/c-programming-check-if-key-pressed-without-stopping-program

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have found a solution

```
void UserPause(void)
{
  printf("Press any key to continue\n");  // Print message to user
  while (!_kbhit())  // Loop while the keyboard is not hit
  {

    if (b_TesterPresentEnabled == 1)  
    // Only do tester present if functionality is enabled
    {
        TestTXMsg[0] = 0x3e;  // Set up the message bytes
        TestTXMsg[1] = 0x00;
        TxMsgLen = 2;  // Define the message length
        MsgTest();  // Function to send the message to the ECU
        Sleep(4000);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure your embedded controller has the `_kbhit()` function available: it's not part of the C Standard... or POSIX.